# How to avoid mapping all children of a TPT inheritance in Code First when needing just one of them in EF 4.4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Table per Type Inheritance already implemented in my system. This is used from the main framework we use in this app, so we shouldn't modify this structure, but, from time to time, new children may be implemented.

Up to now, we didn't need to reference those models directly from our business services and classes, but suddenly we do for one of them. We have a "ContentItem" table as a parent, with around 15 tables as children. I just need to use one child (an as a consequence, parent).

As we're using EF Code First, I've defined the mappings required for the child.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemC>().ToTable("ContentItemC");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemC>().HasKey(c => c.ContentItemId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemC>().HasRequired(c => c.AnotherModel).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.AnotherModel);
```

The thing is, once I do this, I need to map also the parent table, as I will need to use some relationships to other models whose references are in the parent (ContentItemTag for instance). So I do that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItem>().ToTable("ContentItem");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItem>().HasKey(q => q.ContentItemId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItem>().Ignore(ci => ci.FeatureLevel);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItem>().HasRequired(q => q.Status).WithMany().HasForeignKey(q => q.StatusID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItem>().HasMany(q => q.Tags).WithMany()
                .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("ContentItemId").MapRightKey("TagID").ToTable("ContentItemTag"));
```

But here's when the "issue" comes up. Every time I try to get or add a ContentItemC from/to EF Context, the application breaks saying that some properties were not found. Interestingly, these are the properties defined in the other children models. It looks like when adding the parent model to Code First, I'm required to also map the rest of the models. Once I do this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemA>().ToTable("ContentItemA");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemA>().HasKey(c => c.ContentItemId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemB>().ToTable("ContentItemB");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemB>().HasKey(c => c.ContentItemId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemD>().ToTable("ContentItemD");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentItemD>().HasKey(c => c.ContentItemId);

etc.
```

It looks dirty to be forced to add each of these references to models I didn't need to declare before in Code First and that the app won't use directly (but it will break when trying to use the "ContentItemC"). Apart from that, the problem is everytime a ContentItem"X" is added, we're forced to add a dummy declaration for it in the OnModelCreating method. What is worse, it will generate a runtime error only when trying to access ContentItemC, so it will be easy to forget to update the Code First as a result, specially for those who haven't worked on ContentItemC business.

I've thought of generating these modelBuilder rules by reflection, but I don't find it a safe and clean solution either (and will be quite cryptical I think).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Erm...my head hurts. Could you add you POCOs? Or perhaps the POCO you WANT.

Comment: Done. Other children have of course other fields, but some of them may be named the same (Title, IsActive, for instance).

Comment: Have you considered using either a complex property type, or abstract classes for the common properties? I think you want complex types.

Comment: The thing is the idea is not to modify any other model appart from the one I needed to create (ContentItemC). Doing those modifications will impact in the way the framework uses them. The very first problem is I shouldn't handle the ContentItems directly from my application, but as I was required not to modify the framework structure, I'm working with this workaround. Everything works perfect, but I'm worried about the mantainability/possible errors of this solution, just because I'm required to declare explicity all the subclasses mapping. If I could avoid that, my concern would be solved.